# Ajax and Php, after create relationship table, not show inserted data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, foreign-keys

I'm a newbie in Ajax and Php and i would like to solve a doubt that i have about isert data in Mysql table with Bootstrap Modal, Ajax and Php.

So, i have one table that call "tbl_employee" and a page that call "index.php".

In "index.php" i have a Bootstrap modal button that works well when a user click on. After user click on this button, bootstrap modal show a form that when is completed by the user, it clicks the button. After click on "Insert" button, all data that was inputed by the user, is stored in "tbl_employee" normally.

But when i created a relationship in "tbl_employee" table with another table that call "tipo_ps", the user can't insert data in Mysql through Bootstrap Modal form anymore. Below i printed an image to show a column that i created to make the relationship with "tbl_employee" table:

[Relationship - Mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biJ52.png)

In "index.php" page i have the Ajax code below:

```js
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
     var tipo=$("#tipo").val();
  event.preventDefault();  
  if($('#name').val() == "")  
  {  
   alert("Name is required");  
  }  
  else if($('#address').val() == '')  
  {  
   alert("Address is required");  
  }  
  else if($('#designation').val() == '')
  {  
   alert("Designation is required");  
  }
   
  else  
  {  
   $.ajax({  
    url:"insert.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),
    beforeSend:function(){  
     $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
    },  
   success:function(data){  
     $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
     $('#employee_table').html(data);
    }  
   });  
  }  
 });
</script>
```

This code above works fine if I don't create any relationship table. Below is the code (insert.php) that is responsible to insert data in "tbl_employee" table. When I created the relationship I inserted the column "tipo" in the code:

```html
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
if(!empty($_POST))
{
 $output = '';
 $tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tipo']); 
 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);  
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);  
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);  
    $designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['designation']);  
    $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['age']);
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO tbl_employee(tipo, name, address, gender, designation, age)  
     VALUES('$tipo', '$name', '$address', '$gender', '$designation', '$age')
    ";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
    {
     $output .= '<label class="text-success">Data Inserted</label>';
     $select_query = "SELECT tbl_employee.id, tbl_employee.tipo, tbl_employee.name, tipo_ps.tipo FROM (tbl_employee INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON tbl_employee.tipo = tipo_ps.tipo_id)";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select_query);
     $output .= '
      <table class="table table-bordered">  
                    <tr>  
                         <th width="70%">Tipo</th>  
                         <th width="70%">Name</th>
                         <th width="30%">View</th>  
                    </tr>

     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>  
                         <td>' . $row['tipo'] . '</td>  
                         <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>
                         <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="' . $row['id'] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                    </tr>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

As i explain above, when the user click on insert button on bootstrap modal form nothing is display in the "index.php" page, like image below:

[Modal Form - Insert Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPmvK.png)

[Blank page after clicked on "Insert button"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUaXQ.png)

But if a delete the relationship that i created everything works well.

In this case, what can I do, if is possible, to insert data in the "tbl_employee" table with the created relationship?

Thanks a lot for all.

Comment: show us tipo_ps table content

Comment: Hello @Rainmx93, thanks for answered. This is an image of "tipo_ps" table [link](https://ibb.co/hBoNp8) ...

Comment: maybe try change your select querry to this: SELECT tbl_employee.id, tbl_employee.tipo, tbl_employee.name, tipo_ps.tipo FROM tbl_employee INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON tbl_employee.tipo = tipo_ps.tipo_id

Comment: Hi @Rainmx93, Thanks for answered. I replace the code that you give and unfortunately the page "index.php" are still return blank page. But if i delete the table relationship "tbl_employee" colunm "tipo"(FK), the code insert data normally. In this case, should i have change ajax code just because i created the relationship table? Thanks again for the attention.

Comment: is $_POST['tipo'] contains tipo_ps table id?

Comment: actually the collumn "tipo" is in "tbl_employee" as index, type INT(11). This image show "tbl_employee" with collumn "tipo" that is related with "tipo_ps" table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/biJ52.png

Comment: can you show your html file with form?

Comment: i think there is problem with your insert querry

Comment: Sure. This is a link that contains the index.php file. https://ufile.io/cbolp

Comment: try add option value in `echo '<option value="">'.$row['tipo'].'</option>';` change to `echo '<option value="'.$row['tipo_id'].'">'.$row['tipo'].'</option>';`

Comment: I see. I tried to change the query to **SELECT * FROM tbl_employee INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON tbl_employee.tipo = tipo_ps.tipo_id** but continues to return blank page.

Comment: Great. It's working now. I inserted "tipo_id" in option value like you said and works fine. Thanks a lot @Rainmx93.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the problem is in option tag:

```
    if($rowCount > 0) {
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {  
            echo '<option value="">'.$row['tipo'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">Tipo não encontrado</option>';
    }
```

and in insert query you have empty `$tipo` value,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_employee(tipo, name, address, gender, designation, age)  
VALUES('$tipo', '$name', '$address', '$gender', '$designation', '$age')
";
```

So change it to:

```
if($rowCount > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['tipo_id'].'">'.$row['tipo'].'</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<option value="">Tipo não encontrado</option>';
}
```